# FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT not working all time (scenario where that was ignore?)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I get this code

```
public static boolean launchIntent(Activity activity, Intent intent, boolean isBack) {
    try {
        Bundle bundle = isBack ? ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.xml.animation3, R.xml.animation4).toBundle() : ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.xml.animation, R.xml.animation2).toBundle();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, bundle);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error launchIntent");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

All my activity are in singleTop lauchmode (i tried standard mode too), and i pass by this launchintent for every change activity (except back where i let the native onbackpress do the job).

Here is my scenario problem.

When i do A => B => C back => B back => A => B => C (from here all my lauchintent will react like if they ignored my flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) if i go to B => C => B when i back i will go to C to B to C where the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT was supposed to react like to C to A.

```
08-30 15:45:19.266 13124-13124/fr.cora.gestionarticle W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
08-30 15:45:19.266 13124-13124/fr.cora.gestionarticle W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1550)
08-30 15:45:19.267 13124-13124/fr.cora.gestionarticle W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
08-30 15:45:19.267 13124-13124/fr.cora.gestionarticle W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.isTopOfTask(ActivityManagerNative.java:4535)
08-30 15:45:19.267 13124-13124/fr.cora.gestionarticle W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask(Activity.java:5450)
08-30 15:45:19.267 13124-13124/fr.cora.gestionarticle W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3822)
08-30 15:45:19.267 13124-13124/fr.cora.gestionarticle W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
08-30 15:45:19.267 13124-13124/fr.cora.gestionarticle W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
08-30 15:45:19.267 13124-13124/fr.cora.gestionarticle W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4055)
08-30 15:45:19.267 13124-13124/fr.cora.gestionarticle W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivity(ActivityCompatJB.java:27)
08-30 15:45:19.267 13124-13124/fr.cora.gestionarticle W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivity(ActivityCompat.java:134)
08-30 15:45:19.267 13124-13124/fr.cora.gestionarticle W/System.err:     at fr.cora.gestionarticle.helpers.NavigationHelper.launchIntent(NavigationHelper.java:133)
```

If i removed the animation i didn't get the exception but that do not resolved my scenario problem.

Someone now why this flag stop to work in this case (and maybe in other case that i do not find)? And how to resolve it?

If you need more information tel me.

**EDIT 1 :**

What i want to do and work in "normal" use case
A => B => C => B stack of activity should be (are in most of case) A, C, B (reorder pass B to front).

My use case where that didn't work
A => B i back so i return to A and B was destroied. Then i navigate again A => B => C => B and for some reason my stack of activity is A, B, C*, B (the B was recreate and not pass to front).

I get the exception that i give in my launchIntent each time after the second part of navigation (get it from the navigation C mark with "*" in my use case).
When i remove the bundle that set the animation i didn't had the exception anymore but that don't resolve the navigation problem.

That was really strange in "normal" case the flag work fine but after this scenario its like that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: What is a storyboard?

Comment: @LucaZiegler Ah sorry i used this from iOS, that was a scenario. Like i describ with my A => B => C etc...

Comment: Do you mean activities with a/b/c?

Comment: I'm confused about your navigation. If you have A->B->C and you press BACK, C is destroyed. If you press BACK again B is destroyed. If you want to then start B again a new instance of B will be created, even if you use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` because there is no existing active (live) instance of B to be reordered. If this is not your case, please explain in more detail your navigation.

Comment: @DavidWasser i have add an "EDIT 1" to the post, hope that answer to you.

Comment: @DavidWasser i change my use case its like destroy the activity B made something wrong and then the flag reorder is ignore...

Comment: What version of Android are you using or testing on? Have you tried a different version?

Comment: @DavidWasser finally i resolve it. Problem came from the click on a floating button (with lib clans fab) and when i pass the fragment as listener that don't work in this scenario (in normal case thats work), when i pass a custom class clicklistener thats work fine in all case, dunno why... If you was interresting by this case i can give you more explanation and code, for me that work now and i do something that was ok in architect term so...